# jQuery cookie breaking my CSS toggle input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery Cookies and jQuery hide and show in combination with a checkbox toggle to control when prices should be displayed.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
      <div class="slider round">
        <span class="on">Incl</span>
        <span class="off">Excl</span>
      </div>
</label>

<span class="price-excluding-tax">
  <span class="label">Excl. Tax:</span>
  <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-3">€9.99</span>
</span>
<span class="price-including-tax">
  <span class="label">Incl. Tax:</span>
  <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-3">€9.99</span>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){

$(function(){

    ShowPrices();

    $('input#togBtn').click(function(){
        if($.cookie('VATMODE') == "INC"){
            $.cookie('VATMODE', 'EX');
        } else {
             $.cookie('VATMODE', 'INC')
        }
        ShowPrices();
        return false
    });
});


function ShowPrices(){
    if($.cookie('VATMODE') == "INC"){
        $('.price-including-tax').show();
        $('.price-excluding-tax').hide();
    } else {
        $('.price-including-tax').hide();
        $('.price-excluding-tax').show();
    }
}
        })(jQuery);

</script>
```

This is working fine with the exception that jQuery breaks my CSS toggle and for the life of me i cannot figure out why.

Here is a fiddle with the issue (note how the toggle doesnt switch):

https://jsfiddle.net/ra5t0hfo/7/

and the same fiddle with jQuery removed where my toggle works fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/14fy0u3o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your fiddles have jQuery still. It is just one doesn't have the cookies library included. The one that doesn't have the cookies library is the one that works because your click handler is never setup.

This is because your code errors out on the first line of `ShowPrices()`

```
if($.cookie('VATMODE') == "INC"){
```

Because the cookie library isn't there `$.cookie` isn't defined therefore throws an error. If you open up the console (F12 -> console tab, on most browsers) you would see some error like `Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function` This error then has the effect of the rest of your code in the function not running

```
ShowPrices(); //error happens in ShowPrices, execution stops here does not continue

$('input#togBtn').click(function(){
  //...
});
```

The reason the one with the cookies library doesn't work is because the error is never thrown and your click handler is setup. And you `return false` in that handler, which prevents the default action of the checkbox changing state

```js
jQuery("#thecheck").click(function(){ return false });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="thecheck">
```

If you want the checkbox to be toggle-able take out the `return false` statement.

Comment: Thanks i knew it had to be something silly... not related to the question but any thoughts on how to make the checkbox state persist using cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Why returning `false` with `$('input#togBtn')`? Removing the return works.

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ra5t0hfo/11/)